# How initial partitions happens in spark while reading?

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing

Initial `partitions` of data happens on what basis in spark while reading from big csv file ?

How it will decide to have number of partitions/split of large file data into different workers nodes while reading from Big csv file ?

Can anyone share, how its being done ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When reading non-bucketed HDFS files (e.g. parquet) with spark-sql, the number of DataFrame partitions `df.rdd.getNumPartitions` depends on these factors:

```
spark.default.parallelism (roughly translates to #cores available for the application)
spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes (default 128MB)
spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes (default 4MB)
spark.sql.files.minPartitionNum (optional, introduced in spark 3.1)
```

A rough estimation of the number of partitions is:

```
PartitionSize ≈ min(maxPartitionBytes, max(4MB, TotalDataSize/#cores))
NumberOfPartitions ≈ max(TotalDataSize/PartitionSize, minPartitionNum)
```

You can refer [FilePartition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FilePartition.scala#L86) for exact calculation.